# My project display only my homepage without any buttons and other pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

while making this school project i finish the code and make everything right, at least that's what i thought.

I'll put here my app.js and bin section, so if anyone can help me display everything i would appreciate it.

I start it with npm on the localhost as you can see in the picture.

I really need help, i am a student and i know the website is not very awesome but that's what they asked us.

There is the index.hbs file

```
<section> 
    <h1>Welcome to StackPeakFlow.</h1>

    <h3>List of questions</h3>
    <ul>
        {{#each questionTable}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</section>
```

There is the index.js router file

```
const router = express.Router();


const messagesTable = [];



/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index', {
    questionTable: ['Can comments be used in JSON file?', 'How can I center text inside a div block?', 'Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?', 'How do i compare strings in Java?']
  });
});

/* GET question. */
router.get('/question', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('indexQuestion', { messagesTable });
});

/* POST add question. */
router.post('/question/add', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("POST ADD QUESTION");
  messagesTable.push({ message: req.body.message, author: req.body.author });
  res.redirect('/question');
});


module.exports = router;
```

````
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

// Use of sessions
var session = require('express-session')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var questionsRouter = require('./routes/questions');
var membersRouter = require('./routes/members');

var app = express();

// register partials views 
// important to do that before set engine 
// BEFORE app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
var hbs = require('hbs');
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');

//eq
hbs.registerHelper('eq', function (a, b) {
  if (a === b) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({ secret: "Your secret key", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/questions', questionsRouter);
app.use('/members', membersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
``` APP.JS







Here is the bin part with the WWW file
```#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

 var app = require('../app');
 var debug = require('debug')('02-1-exo1-mvc:server');
 var http = require('http');
 
 /**
  * Get port from environment and store in Express.
  */
 
 var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
 app.set('port', port);
 
 /**
  * Create HTTP server.
  */
 
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 
 /**
  * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
  */
 
 server.listen(port);
 server.on('error', onError);
 server.on('listening', onListening);
 
 /**
  * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
  */
 
 function normalizePort(val) {
   var port = parseInt(val, 10);
 
   if (isNaN(port)) {
     // named pipe
     return val;
   }
 
   if (port >= 0) {
     // port number
     return port;
   }
 
   return false;
 }
 
 /**
  * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
  */
 
 function onError(error) {
   if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
     throw error;
   }
 
   var bind = typeof port === 'string'
     ? 'Pipe ' + port
     : 'Port ' + port;
 
   // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
   switch (error.code) {
     case 'EACCES':
       console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
       process.exit(1);
       break;
     case 'EADDRINUSE':
       console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
       process.exit(1);
       break;
     default:
       throw error;
   }
 }
 
 /**
  * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
  */
 
 function onListening() {
   var addr = server.address();
   var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
     ? 'pipe ' + addr
     : 'port ' + addr.port;
   debug('Listening on ' + bind);
 }
````

WWW section

And i'll put you a screenshot of what the page looks while started

[Display site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnZRW.png)

and here are the views files
[views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eMpz.png)

Comment: You have `app.use('/', indexRouter);` so we need to see that route file and what it's rendering. It renders *something*, so maybe the problem is less with the server code and more with the handlebars view?

Comment: okay, i edited the question, i will check that. Thank you

Comment: Ok, so that route is rendering index.hbs, right? Does that view include a navbar with links to the other pages?

Comment: Yes that's right, no it don't have, but i did thats same for my past project and it was working, let me edit it again to you can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html

##### To use the partials, you need to,

1. Register them
2. Call them

You are registering them properly

But looks like you might be forgetting to call them in your `index.hbs`?

###### `header` at the top,

```
{{> header}}
```

###### and `footer` at the bottom,

```
{{> footer}}
```